# Path of a bead on a rod with external torque

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

> Imagine a bead, free to move along the length of a horizontal rod, pivoted at one end. The system is initially at rest, with the bead at some distance from the end. Now, a constant torque is applied to the rod. I want to find the equation of the motion of the bead.

My attempt: (The mass of the bead is $m$, and the moment of inertia of the rod is $I$ and the applied torque is $\tau$)

Writing the force equation along the radial direction in the frame of the rotating rod, I get
$$\ddot r = \omega^2 r$$

Writing external torque as the rate of change of angular momentum, I get
$$\tau = 2m\omega r \dot r + mr^2 \alpha + I \alpha$$

And using the work kinetic energy theorem, I get
$$2\tau \theta= I \omega ^2 + mr^2 \omega^2+ m \dot r ^2$$

I tried a lot, but couldn't figure out how to simplify these equations. I'm totally stuck, and a nudge in the right direction would be really helpful.

Comment: $\theta=\omega\,t$ ?

Comment: First equation is dimensionally incorrect.

Comment: Rhs of first equation should read $m \omega^2 r$

Comment: Sorry I mistyped, i have edited it to the correct equation.